# What are the advantages and disadvantages of each choice for ships doctor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

After arriving a Huerta Memorial hospital, I have a choice. I can bring my old friend Dr. Chakwas aboard the Normandy, or I can ask her to enjoy her retirement for once and bring aboard Dr. Chloe Michel to serve as my ships doctor instead.

Aside from the chance at a token Paragon/Renegade doctor while trying to recruit Dr. Michel, is there any long term difference that comes from bringing one or the other of the two doctors aboard?

Or are the physicians functionally interchangable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you pick Doctor Chakwas you find out her first name and you will share another bottle of Serrice Ice Brandy (if you shared one in ME2).

If you pick Doctor Michel, Doctor Chakwas will stay with Hackett in Alliance R&D and awards you a War Asset (I received +10).  Her background specifically mentions alien physiology so I don't know how that might play out either in helping your team or through some unknown thread in R&D.  She has more dialogue than Chakwas, including info about the implants inside Shepard(Lazarus Project).  You also might get some more info on Banes(ME1), if the rumor that Banes will be back in Mass Effect 3 is correct.

The Normandy Doctor sends you on a quest.  If it's Dr. Chakwas, the reward is a Medi-Gel efficiency upgrade, if it's Michel it's Medi-Gel capacity.

Comment: Dr. Chakwas counts as an asset even if you pick her. But I'm not sure to what degree.

Comment: You can only share "another" bottle of Brandy if you did so in ME2.

Comment: Some people are saying the two doctors have different quests with unique rewards. I know Chakwas sends you to barter with refugees and gives an upgrade to Medi-Gel efficiency (Whatever that does). Any idea about Michel?

Comment: @kotekzot I'll add this to the answer and investigate what I can find about Michel.

Comment: @kotekzot Got it, but I'm out of edits for 17 more minutes.

Comment: So... What exactly is increased Medi-Gel efficiency?

Comment: Cool, thanks! @LessPop_MoreFizz I think it means you get more hearts per application of Unity. Shouldn't matter unless you frequently get down to 1 heart.