# What is my Medi-Gel Capacity?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is there a way to see how many Medi-Gel you can maximum carry at any point in time with out going to limit or knowing your Medi-Gel Capacity level?

[image]

Comment: I dont understand the question...

Comment: What do you mean by "without going to the store before maxing it"?

Comment: I have not maxed my Medi-Gel Capacity, I would like to know if there is a place that shows how many i can carry with out having to max the number i have on me

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: He wants to know how to tell what his max capacity is when he isn't *at* max capacity.

Comment: I understood after he commented however I dont think he can without going to the limit

Comment: Aren't you always at max capacity when your on the Normandy or the Citadel? Can't you just press escape to see that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only way to see your medi gel capacity is to have as many medi gels as you can carry...and also know that you're maxed out.

You can take an educated guess however; you start at 3, and each level of Medi Gel Capacity boosts it by one. Additionally there's a quest you can do for Dr. Michel (maybe also doctor Chakwas?) that increases your capacity by one. Therefore, your character in the screenshot must have 5 or 6 max medigel; they started with three and they must own Med Gel Capacity II already. Only you would know whether you got the extra capacity from the quest.

I'm guessing it wasn't a priority to display it in-game because there's not much you can do about it; you can't intentionally fill up on medi gel, and there's no reason to abandon medi gel if you're maxed, since it gives XP. But ME3 is largely missing an "inventory" screen for items like this.

Comment: (Dr. Chakwas grants a [medi-gel efficiency bonus](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53889/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-each-choice-for-ships-doctor), instead)

Comment: AFAIK, Chakwas' quest does not increase the Medi-Gel capacity. Instead, it makes your Medi-Gel heal one more bar of health per use.

Comment: @TimStone they're actually both referred to ask medi-gel efficiency in-game. Does Michel's upgrade raise capacity by *two* units though? I noticed I have five medigel now, and I never bought an upgrade, only did Michel's quest.