# What's been enhanced in the enhanced Medi-gel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The reward for completing the *Citadel: Medical Supplies* is either increased Medi-gel capacity or enhanced Medi-gel depending on which doctor is stationed on Normandy.

The increased capacity is self-explanatory. However, I do not understand what "enhancement" has been given to the enhanced Medi-gel. Is it simply that the amount of health restored through the use Medi-gel has been increased? **What exactly puts the "enhanced" in "enhanced Medi-gel"?**

Comment: it heals more bars, I'm not sure how many though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enhanced medi-gel heals more per use, how much your gel heals is determined by what difficulty you're playing on. So this would be more useful if you're on a higher difficulty than if you were on an easy one.

Answer (score 1):

The medi-gel enhancement basically DOUBLES your current medi-gel count, but the change is very subtle and easy-to-miss.

If you have 4 medi-gels after the enhancement, then using the medi-gel once will not reduce the number to 3 medi-gels on the power-wheel. You'll have to use it a second time for the number of medi-gels on your power-wheel to decrease to 3 medi-gels.

This is based on me playing the 360 version.

Comment: You should use italics or bold for emphasis instead of caps. Otherwise, nice first answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it makes your Medi-Gel heal one more bar of health per use.

Comment: My medi-gel already heals me to full on use... does this change on the higher difficulties?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't know, I have the enhanced med-gel my self and get healed to full on normal difficulty, i got the answer form a comment on one of my earlier questions answer http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56020/13269